# Low TPS with JPOS client

Tags: jpos

We are using JPOS as a client where we have a mux-pool with 4 muxes. Each mux is connected with
a channel-adaptor and the mux-pool strategy is round-robin. We use this setup so we can stress test the end host (where our channels connect)

It seems for some reason we cannot achieve a TPS of higher than 100. At the first few minutes all look good, but as time passes by, some channels do not keep up, which results in lower overall tps.

Is there a way to see if this is a JPOS limitation or maybe a network issue? e.g. the send buffer is full

Any other recommendations are welcomed

Answer (score 0):

One method to consider would be to use a simulator based on https://github.com/jpos/jPOS-EE/tree/master/modules/server-simulator - and point your channels to simulators based on this module. You can try to run this locally e.g on local host or another a server over a network - That will help localize the issue and help you test your channel/mux setup. I’m aware of many jPOS based systems that run higher than 100 TPS using jPOS. Good Luck !